# Accordion menu with parent link also referring to some content

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and looks like I need your help after not being able to get any thing from google. I have a normal accordion menu with menus (level-1) and submenus (level-2). In most cases, only the level-2 links point to a href link and the level-1 is just like a header, but in some cases, I need the level-1 link to lets say fetch some HTML content. So basically, when you click on the parent menu, it would fetch the html content and at the same time the submenu would show.

Below is my code. When I click the level-1 link, at the address bar it shows the # sign which is because in the second line of my code I have the href value assigned as a # sign. If I remove the value, then it goes to the page I want and shows the toggled menu (level-2) as well, but level-2 menu disappears quickly. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


var submenu = $(location).attr('href').substring(url.lastIndexOf('/'), url.length);

var LinkObj = $('a[href*="' + submenu + '"]').parent();
$('.mainmenunav').find(LinkObj).parent().show();


    SelLink = $('.mainmenunav').find(LinkObj).parent();


            $('.level-1 > li > a').click(function(){

                 if (SelLink != null && SelLink.html() != $(this).next().html()){
                    SelLink.slideToggle(800);
                }

                $(this).next().slideToggle(400);

                if (SelLink != null && SelLink.html() == $(this).next().html()){
                    SelLink = null;
                }else{
                    SelLink = $(this).next();
                }
            });

    });
```

The HTML view:

```
<ul id="mainmenunav">
    <li>Sport
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tennis</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I click the level-1 link, at the address bar it shows the # sign which is because in the second line of my code I have the href value assigned as a # sign. If I remove the value, then it goes to the page I want and shows the toggled menu (level-2) as well, but level-2 menu disappears quickly. Don't get the reason.

Comment: what u mean 'load a page'. Is that link make a new Http request or XMLHttp request. If it is Http why you gonna slide the children items.

Comment: I want the level-1 link to make a HTTP request and at the same time show the level-2 links. With the reply RemarkLima has given below, the link goes to the wanted page required and also shows the submenus, but the submenus close again fast.

Comment: @Adia I see what you mean now... As you're loading a new page, it'll always revert to the "loaded" state, unless you load the page into an iFrame or some other trickery. My preference here would be to check on page load for the right page and show the menu accordingly. I'll edit my answer below to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Actually Liferay itself does half of the job; it just needs some tweaking and plus some jQuery as in my first post for the toggling and disabling some of the links.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your HTML markup as well please? Or a sample of?

I'd have thought that you should be able to keep the `href` attribute on those links and they'd still work as expected (unless you call `preventDefault()` in your jQuery).

You could try something like:

```
$('.level-1').click(function(){ 

    // Toggle up and down the menu on click 

    if ($(this).attr('href').length > -1) {
        // The target has a href attribute and it's longer than nothing
        location.href=$(this).attr('href');
    } elseif ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){ 
        level-2.slideUp('normal'); 
        $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal'); 
        level-1.removeClass('active'); 
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
    }  
});
```

The code is off the top of my head, so may need to be tweaked a little.

So it'll take the `href` attribute and use that to redirect the browser. I've done it this way as you're using a click event to expand the accordian - so I'm guessing the ones with links will not have any child elements?

The "usual" is to use a mouseover event for sub menus, and then the click events can be au naturale.

---

Edit: From your comments, I think it's best to check the page name with the href and action the click "manually", so in addition to the above, use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This code fire once the page has loaded
    if(location.pathname != "/")
    {
      // Should select the link which has the same href as the current page
      $("a[href*=" + location.pathname + "]").addClass('active');

     }
});
```

You may need to add some more functionality to the code as I'm not au fait with the theme in question, however the concept is that once the new page has been loaded (remember that HTTP has no memory, so doesn't know what it's state was on the last page), we check page address, and match it to a `href` attribute, then execute the dropdown as required.

Comment: Thanks RemarkLima for the reply. I am building the web pages using Liferay theme, so basically I am working with CSS stuff and no HTML coding, but to clear up the things more, I added a sample HTML code to my first post that would describe my menu. For example, in the News menu, I have also a link. This link in Liferay is automatically created, and the link structure is like this: http://test.com/test1/testlink, with testlink being the name of the parent link.

Answer (score 0):

@RemarkLima I have done something similar to that above as well, as you see below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.level-1 > li > a').attr('href','#');

var submenu = $(location).attr('href').substring(url.lastIndexOf('/'), url.length);

var LinkObj = $('a[href*="' + submenu + '"]').parent();
$('.mainmenunav').find(LinkObj).parent().show();


    SelLink = $('.mainmenunav').find(LinkObj).parent();


            $('.level-1 > li > a').click(function(){

                 if ($(this).attr('href').length > -1) {
                        location.href=$(this).attr('href');

                } else if(SelLink != null && SelLink.html() != $(this).next().html()){
                    SelLink.slideToggle(800);
                }

                $(this).next().slideToggle(400);

                if (SelLink != null && SelLink.html() == $(this).next().html()){
                    SelLink = null;
                }else{
                    SelLink = $(this).next();
                }
            });

    });
```

When I click the level-1 link, at the address bar it shows the # sign which is because in the second line of my code I have the href value assigned as a # sign. If I remove the value, then it goes to the page I want and shows the toggled menu (level-2) as well, but level-2 menu disappears quickly. Don't get the reason.